# Not able to filter column in Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to filter the result using sql developer. I got the process to filter the record as right click on column header and select "Columns" option. but In my sql developer there is no option like columns.

[image: SQL Developer]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, is to use the filter input line, not the column filter.

And then just type: `column_name like '%value_to_search%'`

Example: `NAME like '%john%'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer Version 3.2.20.10, after running a query you can bring up filter on column dialogue box by one of two methods:

1. Click on the column heading (EMPLOYEE_ID in the screen shot below)
2. Right click on column heading (Again EMPLOYEE_ID) and select "Filter Column"

[image]